# I recently getting a error when i updating my angular project 9.0.7 to 9.1.9

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, generics, angular9

Recently, I am getting some error. when I update my angular project 9.0.7 to 9.1.9. This time i get this type of errors.

```
ERROR in ../AppState/node_modules/@angular/core/core.d.ts:256:18 - error TS2314: Generic type 'ɵɵFactoryDef' requires 1 type argument(s).

256     static ɵfac: ɵngcc0.ɵɵFactoryDef<ApplicationInitStatus, [{ optional: true; }]>;
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../AppState/node_modules/@angular/core/core.d.ts:439:18 - error TS2314: Generic type 'ɵɵFactoryDef' requires 1 type argument(s).

439     static ɵfac: ɵngcc0.ɵɵFactoryDef<ApplicationRef, never>;
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../AppState/node_modules/@angular/core/core.d.ts:785:18 - error TS2314: Generic type 'ɵɵFactoryDef' requires 1 type argument(s).

785     static ɵfac: ɵngcc0.ɵɵFactoryDef<Compiler, never>;
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../AppState/node_modules/@angular/core/core.d.ts:5028:18 - error TS2314: Generic type 'ɵɵFactoryDef' requires 1 type argument(s).

5028     static ɵfac: ɵngcc0.ɵɵFactoryDef<PlatformRef, never>;
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../AppState/node_modules/@angular/core/core.d.ts:6414:18 - error TS2314: Generic type 'ɵɵFactoryDef' requires 1 type argument(s).

6414     static ɵfac: ɵngcc0.ɵɵFactoryDef<SystemJsNgModuleLoader, [null, { optional: true; }]>;
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../AppState/node_modules/@angular/core/core.d.ts:6611:18 - error TS2314: Generic type 'ɵɵFactoryDef' requires 1 type argument(s).

6611     static ɵfac: ɵngcc0.ɵɵFactoryDef<Testability, never>;
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../AppState/node_modules/@angular/core/core.d.ts:6656:18 - error TS2314: Generic type 'ɵɵFactoryDef' requires 1 type argument(s).

6656     static ɵfac: ɵngcc0.ɵɵFactoryDef<TestabilityRegistry, never>;
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../AppState/node_modules/@angular/core/core.d.ts:9555:18 - error TS2314: Generic type 'ɵɵFactoryDef' requires 1 type argument(s).

9555     static ɵfac: ɵngcc0.ɵɵFactoryDef<ɵConsole, never>;
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../AppState/node_modules/@datorama/akita/lib/store.d.ts:138:18 - error TS2314: Generic type 'ɵɵFactoryDef' requires 1 type argument(s).

138     static ɵfac: ɵngcc0.ɵɵFactoryDef<Store<any>, never>;
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **
```

I could not understand what is the problem. please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have two and more angular projects in the same directory. Where my another angular application name is `AppState`. Which is the outside of my current project. there dependencies connect with my project And here i was getting my problem for that.

This Error getting from dependencies. Here i am using this. `npm install @datorama/akita-ng-entity-service` this syntax. then i get the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Delete and reinstall your node modules

update your angular CLI

```
ng update @angular/cli @angular/core)
```

and your Typescript

```
npm install -g typescript@latest
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am trying your solution packages are updated but problem does not resolved.

Comment: Did you delete your node modules before those updates ? if you didn't , do it

Comment: Yes, i delete node_modules folder then I install the packages. But also getting same errors.

Comment: try to 'npm cache verify' , if it doesn't work you can try here: https://blog.angular.io/version-9-1-of-angular-now-available-typescript-3-8-faster-builds-and-more-eb292f989428

Comment: `Cache verified and compressed (~/.npm/_cacache):
Content verified: 1254 (118753321 bytes)
Content garbage-collected: 6 (11088715 bytes)
Index entries: 1309
Finished in 6.434s`

Comment: Problem is Same.

Comment: I am using ` "@datorama/akita": "^4.23.2",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.0",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "moment": "^2.26.0",
    "ng-marquee": "^9.5.0",` these additional support packages in my application.